# Will expanding an EBS ext3 file system cause corruption?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ext3

We're using ext3 right now for our EBS file systems and I was wondering if there would be any problems with the following scenario for expanding the size.

1. Create EBS initial size 2GB (ebs1)
2. Snapshot EBS (s1)
3. Create 10GB EBS (ebs2) from snapshot (s1)

Will this corrupt the file system? Will the ext3 file system automatically handle this situation? Likewise, will decreasing the size, using the same method, cause any problems (assuming the space is still sufficient for the data)?

I have successfully done this in the EC2 environment but since I'm currently using very little data I'm not sure if I've caused any problems.

Would running fsck find issues like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the underlying partition size doesn't autoexpand the filesystem.  You need to run resize2fs to resize the filesystem on that partition - expanding can be done with the filesystem mounted, but shrinking requires unmounting first.

Note: the above is general in application; I haven't used EBS or EC2 in this way, but have no reason to believe it would be any different.